# Can you curve views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I want to curve views so that objects will pop out. I am registering lanes and the views will be lanes. Can i curve views in the nib file

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `UIView` with a non rectangular shape, but you can mask it using a `CALayer` with any random shape. See [Bitmap Images and Image Masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101).